# Is 100,000 faces a big render? How can I reduce it?

Tags: modeling

I'm making a human body. It has 70,000 faces so far, and I still have to make the face. In weight paint mode, it lags. How can I reduce this without making it look less smooth?[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the lag if the subdivision hasn't been applied? Would taking the subdivision off while weight painting help? Will 70,000 faces cause issues after export?

Answer (score 1):

100,000 is a lot of faces on a slow computer, but not too many on a fast computer (definitely not unrealistically high). As a general rule, always stay as low-poly as possible for as long as you can, and use a subdivision modifier to add the look of smoothness while maintaining an easy-to-edit lower-poly mesh for edit/weight paint/etc. modes. Don't apply the subdiv modifier unless you have to. If you can get away with it, never apply it. Rigs will live perfectly well underneath or on top of a subdiv modifier. Working like that helps your viewport stay nice and smooth!

In your case--since it seems you've already applied a smooth or two to your model, you may be able to reduce your poly-count by using the [decimate modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/generate/decimate.html), but that's sort of hit or miss and may require a bit of touch-up.

Comment: Will it lag in a game engine?

Comment: Look above I added an image of the topology

Comment: Still depends on the computer. You should generally keep game topology as low as you can get away with, though, and bake higher details in via normal maps.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: There are lots of resources on the web for that. Searching "How to bake normal maps in Blender" on Google would be a good start. The second search result on that page looks like a good place to start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTGTUd0pCaQ

Comment: but how can I subdivide bake it?

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand your question. Normal map baking is all pretty similar.

Comment: I now understand, however I'm having issues. Can you look at my new question?